# Sheets - Lookup most recent entry based on unsorted date value

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Spreadsheet Im working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rTzdmKVMqD8sz1D639y5qgvXNBcWaAuBaQOAmwJXdA4/edit#gid=0

I need a formula that returns the `Comment` for the `Domain` that equals the `search key:` with the most recent `Timestamp` when `Timestamp` is unsorted.
You can see in my example I have tried using both `INDEX` and `VLOOKUP` but with no success.

Actual spreadsheet has over 5000 rows and multiple sheets, and is quite complex, therefore a `QUERY` statement is too inefficient and causes the sheet to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

(following OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/144142/sheets-lookup-most-recent-entry-based-on-unsorted-date-value/144145?noredirect=1#comment131702_144145))

*Unfortunately I hadn't put quite enough detail in. This only returns the most recent comment, not the **most recent comment for the domain I am looking for** - I have [edited](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/144142/3) the question with the extra details.*

In this case you should also take advantage of the **[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)** function

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(QUERY(A1:F,"where B=' "&H7&" ' ")),A1:F,5,0)
```

where `H7` is the cell containing the domain you are looking for.

---

Please use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(A1:A),A1:F,5,0)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`MAX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt!  Unfortunately I hadn't put quite enough detail in.  This only returns the most recent comment, not the most recent `comment` for the `domain` I am looking for - I have edited the question with the extra details.

Comment: Thanks again - I have edited to include details as to why a `QUERY` will not work.

Comment: By [continuously editing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/144142/revisions) your question and adding new parameters you have completely changed the original question. This can be very confusing for future users of the site. In any case, to lessen the load of the query function you can use `=VLOOKUP(MAX(QUERY(A1:B,"where B='"&H7&"' ")),{A1:A,E1:E},2,0)`. Still. I would suggest you accept this answer and if still in need, create a new question.

Comment: Marked as solved. I edited to add more detail that I didn't realise would be necessary, in the hope it will also less confusing for future users, which is certainly my intent. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to accept. If you are still in need please do post a new question.

Comment: A pleasure.  I did ask a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/144237/in-google-sheets-find-most-recent-comment-for-a-domain), hopefully with the new data it will be simpler to answer.

Comment: Great. Well done.