# In Google Sheets, find most recent comment for a domain

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Using this sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SFXBBlgX6KoffGqQ3HHsRmFcDurGiUjFLYXT3igy8Nk/edit?usp=sharing

On the `Demo` sheet, please help me display the most `Recent Comment` from the `Log` sheet.

As you can see in the sheet, currently I am using `=QUERY(Log!$A$2:F,"Select E Where B='" & A2 & "' ORDER BY A Desc LIMIT 1",-1)` but in a sheet this size (5000+ domains and 5000+ comments), its very inefficient and takes too long to update, breaking other connected sheets.  Is there a way to make it more efficient?

### Sample data

**LOG sheet**

```
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| Timestamp           | Domain             |  |  | Comment             |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 01/12/2019 00:00:00 | random domain 1454 |  |  | random comment 1944 |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 01/12/2019 00:00:00 | random domain 3245 |  |  | random comment 476  |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 01/12/2019 00:00:00 | random domain 3653 |  |  | random comment 4837 |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 01/12/2019 00:00:00 | random domain 3907 |  |  | random comment 1761 |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 12/12/2019 00:00:00 | random domain 1043 |  |  | random comment 3703 |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 12/12/2019 00:00:00 | random domain 1891 |  |  | random comment 958  |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 12/12/2019 00:00:00 | random domain 2821 |  |  | random comment 1590 |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 12/12/2019 00:00:00 | random domain 3005 |  |  | random comment 962  |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
| 12/12/2019 0:00:00  | random domain 3282 |  |  | random comment 1188 |
+---------------------+--------------------+--+--+---------------------+
```

---

**DEMO sheet**

```
+-----------------+------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| Domain          | Slug | Date Applied | Provider | Status | Payment type | Recent Comment      |
+-----------------+------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| random domain 1 |      |              |          |        |              | random comment 2821 |
+-----------------+------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| random domain 2 |      |              |          |        |              | random comment 639  |
+-----------------+------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| random domain 3 |      |              |          |        |              | random comment 1849 |
+-----------------+------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| random domain 4 |      |              |          |        |              | random comment 2257 |
+-----------------+------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
```

---

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. All the relevant details to answer the question should be included in the question body, i.e. the structure of the Log sheet and some sample data.

Comment: @Rubén I agree. The question should (ideally) reflect all the information, and not rely on viewing in a spreadsheet, though I never knew how this might be done Via the meta, I found [tablesgenerator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables), and I think it does a good job. For information of others, pasted from spreadsheet, generated 
 online, copied to clipboard, pasted into question, then used markdown "pre-formatted" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`={ARRAYFORMULA(ifna(VLOOKUP(A2:A1000, SORT({Log!B2:B, Log!A2:A, Log!E2:E}, 2, false), 3, 0)))}`

Enter this formula is cell G2 of Sheet="Demo".

The logic is:

- `SORT`: sorts the ranges of Logs by the Timestamp, descending. Note that the whole of the "Logs" data is NOT sorted;

  - "Domain" (Column B) (moved to the first column so it can be used with VLOOKUP),
  - "Timestamp" (Column A) (moved to the second column) and the column that is sorted,
  - "Comment" (Column E) which moved to the 3rd column.
- `VLOOKUP`: lookup the "Domain" (Column A) in the sorted "Logs" range; returns the value in the 3rd column (Comment).
- `IFNA`: returns a blank instead of an "#N/A" error message.
- `ARRAYFORMULA`: enables the formula to be executed in rows 2 to 1000.

Props to @player0 for the initial solution in
StackOvereflow

[Arrayformula to find next value for criteria in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60104128/1330560)